# bluetooth sink does not show in pulseaudio after successful bluetooth device connection

Tags: linux, bluetooth, pulse-audio, gdm, bluez

Bluetooth output does not show anymore in pavucontrol "Playback" tab after successful bluetooth device connection  and therefore does not output any sound into the bluetooth device.

```bash
$ bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:04 sebastien-B206 [default]
[NEW] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 PROZOR RX5.0
[bluetooth]# connect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
Attempting to connect to 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

Pulse-audio bluetooth sinks :

```bash
$ pactl list sinks short | grep bluez_sink
$
```

Pulse-audio bluetooth modules :

```bash
$ pactl list modules short | grep module-blue
8   module-bluetooth-policy     
9   module-bluetooth-discover       
10  module-bluez5-discover      
$
```

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution was to disable `pulseaudio` in GDM because  `pulseaudio` instance of GDM was "stealing" the bluetooth sink from `$USER`.

So here's what I did thanks to [Gnome_with_GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Gnome_with_GDM) :

```bash
$ ps -fC pulseaudio
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
gdm       1858     1  0 14:27 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
sebasti+  3263     1  2 14:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
$ gdm_home=$(grep gdm /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6)
$ sudo -u gdm mkdir -pv $gdm_home/.config/pulse/ $gdm_home/.config/systemd/user/
$ sudo test ! -s $gdm_home/.config/pulse/client.conf && printf "autospawn = no\ndaemon-binary = /bin/true\n" | sudo -u gdm tee $gdm_home/.config/pulse/client.conf
autospawn = no
daemon-binary = /bin/true
$ sudo -u gdm ln -vs /dev/null $gdm_home/.config/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket
'/var/lib/gdm3/.config/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket' -> '/dev/null'
$ sudo reboot
$ ps -fC pulseaudio
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
sebasti+  3024     1  0 15:03 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
$ pactl list modules short | grep blue
8   module-bluetooth-policy
9   module-bluetooth-discover
10  module-bluez5-discover
31  module-bluez5-device    path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_97_40_B1_EF_BD_54
$ { echo disconnect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54;sleep 2;echo connect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54;sleep 2; } | bluetoothctl 2>/dev/null | egrep -i "(dis)?connect(ion|ed)?|successful"
[bluetooth]# disconnect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
Attempting to disconnect from 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
Successful disconnected
[bluetooth]# connect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
Attempting to connect to 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Connected: yes
Connection successful
$ pactl list sinks short | grep bluez_sink
4   bluez_sink.97_40_B1_EF_BD_54    module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
$ pactl list sink-inputs short
0   0   8   protocol-native.c   float32le 2ch 44100Hz
$ pactl move-sink-input 0 4
$
```

Comment: I had a similar situation, there were two users with desktop sessions on my computer, one was  my VNC user and other my real user, and the VNC user was getting the audio device instead of my real user. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: You may also simply close pulseaudio on the other user:

```bash
ssh otheruser@localhost
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
```